# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x93c3(unknown) for fragment {4660a7b} - (react-native - android)

Tags: java, android, react-native

building native views in android side so can use it in react-native, problem is that in the first render i can create many instance i want, but when navigating to a new screen and using the same component to create the same native view i get this error:

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x93c3 (unknown) for fragment MyFragment{4660a7b} (1fddb7f4-9894-4da7-a39c-ae82aadfd9aa id=0x93c3 tag=37827)
```

im following the same example as the docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-android#integration-with-an-android-fragment-example just changing its value for mine, but still getting the error.

in android side i have this:

```
//class where i create my fragment

public class MyViewManager extends ViewGroupManager<FrameLayout> {

    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "MyViewManager";
    public final int COMMAND_CREATE = 1;
    private int propWidth;
    private int propHeight;
    private int old_value = 0;
    protected String zone_id;
    private String publisher_id;
    FragmentManager fragmet;
    private ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

    public MyViewManager(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        this.reactContext = reactContext;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    /**
     * Return a FrameLayout which will later hold the Fragment
     */
    @Override
    public FrameLayout createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        return new FrameLayout(reactContext);
    }

    /**
     * Map the "create" command to an integer
     */
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Map<String, Integer> getCommandsMap() {
        return MapBuilder.of("create", COMMAND_CREATE);
    }

    /**
     * Handle "create" command (called from JS) and call createFragment method
     */
    @Override
    public void receiveCommand(
            @NonNull FrameLayout root,
            String commandId,
            @Nullable ReadableArray args
    ) {
        super.receiveCommand(root, commandId, args);
        int reactNativeViewId = args.getInt(0);
        int commandIdInt = Integer.parseInt(commandId);
        this.old_value = reactNativeViewId;

        switch (commandIdInt) {
            case COMMAND_CREATE:
                Log.e("MediumRectangle", "EJECUTAMOS AQUQUIQ" + Integer.toString(reactNativeViewId));
                createFragment(root, reactNativeViewId);
                break;
            default: {}
        }
    }

    @ReactPropGroup(names = {"width", "height", "backgroundColor"}, customType = "Style")
    public void setStyle(FrameLayout view, int index, Integer value) {
        if (index == 0) {
            propWidth = value;
        }

        if (index == 1) {
            propHeight = value;
        }
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "zone_id")
    public void setAdType(FrameLayout view, String zone_id) {
        this.zone_id = zone_id;
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "publisher_id")
    public void setPublisherId(FrameLayout view, String publisher_id) {
        this.publisher_id = publisher_id;
    }

    /**
     * Replace your React Native view with a custom fragment
     */
    public void createFragment(FrameLayout root, int reactNativeViewId) {

        Log.e("MediumRectangle", "CRAETETETT FRAGMEENTNETETTE fragment" + Integer.toString(reactNativeViewId));

        ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) root.findViewById(reactNativeViewId);
        setupLayout(parentView);

        final MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment(reactNativeViewId, this.reactContext, this.zone_id, publisher_id);
        FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity) reactContext.getCurrentActivity();
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(reactNativeViewId, myFragment, String.valueOf(reactNativeViewId))
            .commit();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(reactNativeViewId);
        if (fragment ==  null) {
            Log.e("MediumRectangle", "existetet viwewe");
        }else {
            Log.e("MediumRectangle", "no existete view");
        }
    }

    public void setupLayout(View view) {
        Choreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(new Choreographer.FrameCallback() {
            @Override
            public void doFrame(long frameTimeNanos) {
                manuallyLayoutChildren(view);
                view.getViewTreeObserver().dispatchOnGlobalLayout();
                Choreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(this);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Layout all children properly
     */
    public void manuallyLayoutChildren(View view) {
        // propWidth and propHeight coming from react-native props
        int width = propWidth;
        int height = propHeight;

        view.measure(
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));

        view.layout(0, 0, width, height);
    }
}
```

```
// class of my fragment

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    CustomView customView;

    int viewID;
    ReactApplicationContext reactContext;
    String zone_id;
    String publisher_id;

    protected int getContentViewLayoutId() { return R.layout.activity_display_ad_test; }
    protected int getAdContainerLayoutId() { return R.id.engage_ad; }

    public MyFragment(int reactNativeViewId, ReactApplicationContext reactContext, String zone_id, String publisher_id) {
        this.viewID = reactNativeViewId;
        this.reactContext = reactContext;
        this.zone_id = zone_id;
        this.publisher_id = publisher_id;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);
        customView = new CustomView(this.getContext(), this.reactContext, this.publisher_id);
        return customView; // this CustomView could be any view that you want to render
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // do any logic that should happen in an `onCreate` method, e.g:
        //customView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // do any logic that should happen in an `onPause` method
        // e.g.: customView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // do any logic that should happen in an `onResume` method
        // e.g.: customView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // do any logic that should happen in an `onDestroy` method
        // e.g.: customView.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

and this is the custom view that will appear in the fragment:

```
public class CustomView extends FrameLayout implements AdExecutor.AdLoadCallback, IMAdEngage.AdEventCallback {

    private IMAdSdk sdk_;
    private ReactApplicationContext context;
    private EngageAd banner;
    private ViewGroup container;
    private String zone_id;

    protected int getContentViewLayoutId() { return R.layout.activity_display_ad_test; }
    protected int getAdContainerLayoutId() { return R.id.engage_ad; }

    public CustomView(@NonNull Context context, ReactApplicationContext reactContext, String publisher_id) {

        super(context);

        // set padding and background color
        this.setPadding(16,16,16,16);
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5FD3F3"));

        // add default text view
        TextView text = new TextView(context);
        text.setText("Welcome to Android Fragments with React Native.");
        this.addView(text);

     }
}
```

in javascript side i just do:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { requireNativeComponent, PixelRatio, UIManager, findNodeHandle, Dimensions, View } from 'react-native';

const MyViewManager = requireNativeComponent('MyViewManager');

const Innity = () => {

  const AD_HEIGHT = PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(250);
  const AD_WIDTH = PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(Dimensions.get("window").width);

  const ref = useRef(null);
  const id_ref = useRef(null);
  const [id, setID] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    create();
  }, []);

  const create = () => {
    const viewId = findNodeHandle(ref.current);
      UIManager.dispatchViewManagerCommand(
        viewId,
        // we are calling the 'create' command
        UIManager.MyViewManager.Commands.create.toString(),
        [viewId],
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <View
      style = {{
        height: 250,
        backgroundColor: "transparent"
      }}
    >
      <MyViewManager
        style={{
            height: AD_HEIGHT,
            width: AD_WIDTH
        }}
        zone_id = {"medium_rectangle"}
        publisher_id = {"5613"}
        ref={ref}
      >
      </MyViewManager> 
    </View>
  );
}

export default Innity;
```

in works in the first render, but like i said when navigation to a new screen and trying to create new instance the error comes out, it has something to do with fragment in android but im newbiew with android studio so dont what to do, searched and tried everything